# Terminate a java application from Delphi program

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How can I kill a process which is started by ShellExecute() in Delphi 7.  When clicking a button a java application is opened. It works perfectly. I need to close the process by clicking another button. How can I terminate the java application from delphi?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have the Process ID and need to close the associate process programatically with Delphi 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550927/i-have-the-process-id-and-need-to-close-the-associate-process-programatically-wit)

Comment: @Ken In this case it is going to be easier to get the process handle as the process is created rather than hunting around for a process handle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delphi - Gracefully Closing Created Process in Service. (using tprocess / createProcess)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268208/delphi-gracefully-closing-created-process-in-service-using-tprocess-createp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case you would be better to use [`ShellExecuteEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762154%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to start the process. This allows you to obtain the newly created process handle which is not returned by `ShellExecute`. Once you have that you simply call [`TerminateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686714%28VS.85%29.aspx). As yet another alternative, you may consider creating the process with [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx).